# Flutter json.decode() sometimes works and sometimes doesnt while parsing the same object

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and was working with json. when I am decoding the response I got from the server by using `json.decode()` I sometimes get the following error

```
flutter: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 21)
```

sometimes it works perfectly.

**this is my code**

```
try {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = new Map<String, dynamic>.from(
        json.decode(contents));
    if (map["CompletedJobPackages"] != null) {
      DataStream.compleatedJobspackage =
          DataStream.parseCompletedJobs(map["CompletedJobPackages"]);
      print(map["CompletedJobPackages"]);
      compleatedJobs = DataStream.compleatedJobspackage;
    }
    CompletedJobloaded = true;
  }
  catch(e){
    print(e);
    ToastUtils.showCustomToast(context, "An Error Occured. Try Again !", false);

  }
```

this is the object I'm trying to decode

```
{
            "CompletedJob": {
                "CompletedJobID": 7,
                "DriverID": 34,
                "JobNumber": "80252C20",
                "TraderID": 7,
                "TripType": "Two Way",
                "CargoType": "wd",
                "CargoWeight": 230,
                "LoadingPlace": "dc",
                "UnloadingPlace": "sd",
                "LoadingDate": "2020-05-25",
                "LoadingTime": "12:59:00",
                "EntryExit": 1,
                "AcceptedDelay": 4,
                "Price": 34,
                "Created": "2020-05-23T04:22:10.000Z"
            },
            "BillPaid": 0,
            "DriverReview": {
                "DriverReviewID": 11,
                "DriverID": 34,
                "TraderID": 7,
                "CompletedJobID": 7,
                "Rating": 100,
                "Review": "dscsdc",
                "Created": "2020-05-28"
            }
        },
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable library

Comment: @dubace hi thanks for the response. I tried that as well but I'm still facing the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so after doing a little research I realized the problem.
the HTTP library I was using `dart:io` was not returning the complete JSON string in the response thus their was a problem in converting it into a JSON object

I just used

```
   import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

   Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization':"JWT "+DataStream.token
    };
    final response = await http.get(URLs.getCompletedJobPackagesURL(), headers:requestHeaders);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);

      print(jsonResponse);

      Map<String, dynamic> map = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);

       if(map["CompletedJobPackages"]!= null) {
         DataStream.compleatedJobspackage =
             DataStream.parseCompletedJobs(map["CompletedJobPackages"]);
         compleatedJobs = DataStream.compleatedJobspackage;

       }
  
       setState(() {
       });

    }
```

instead of

```
import 'dart:io';

final client = HttpClient();
try{
final request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(URLs.getDrivingLicenceURL()));
request.headers.set(HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
request.headers.add("Authorization", "JWT "+DataStream.token);
final response = await request.close();

response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((contents) async {
 // print(response.statusCode);
  Map<String, dynamic> driverMap = jsonDecode(contents) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  isloadlicence = true;

  if(driverMap["CompletedJobPackages"]!= null) {
    DataStream.compleatedJobspackage =
    new DrivingLicence.fromJson(driverMap["CompletedJobPackages"]);

  }
  setState(() {

  });
});


 }catch(e){

  print(e);
  ToastUtils.showCustomToast(context, "An Error Occurred. Try Again !", false);
  //pr.hide();

  }
```

Comment: I am using the http package, but I am facing this issue. It works perfectly fine sometimes, and then other times, it doesn't and gives me the same error as yours.

Comment: Hello Zabeeh I realised the issue was occurring when there was large amount of data returned from server i.e thousands of records so the library was somehow getting incomplete data from server (several records were missing) and thus JSON object was broken. try to check if you're getting all the expected data

Comment: Seems so.. I will see if this happens in production as well, though it looks like it just happens on the emulator during development. Anyway, thank you for the insight :)

Comment: yes, do let me know if it happens on a real device / production. when this issue arrived somehow it didn't cross my mind to test it on a real device. Good Luck!

Comment: Hi, Farhan! I just tested it on a real device in release mode and it works fine. I do not face the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the problem is the emulator, after several days looking for the problem I found this post and I have verified that it does not fail on my real phone.

Different emulators fails different number of times (maybe something related to the ram??).

Also consider using `compute(jsonDecode, response.body)` to decode the string as indicated in [Parse JSON in the background](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing).

`compute` fails less times on emulators, but still failing sometimes. Doesn't fails in real phone.